# pentaho-report-designer group records visible

Tags: java, pentaho-report-designer

Here is a requirement: If a group records number is less than 3，this group should not be visible. I am using pentaho report designer group tools，below is the report configuration:

[image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51T4y.png)]

How could I make the group invisible when the group records number is less than 3?